# Symfony2 PHPUnit testing class with services

Tags: php, symfony

I am working with Symfony2 and trying to do some phpunit testing. The class i am trying to test is has two services injected:

```
ValidationClass
DatabaseRepository
```

I have created a test file for this class 'MyTemplateTest.php' under Test/Template directory.

My test file:

```
<?php

namespace Fun\FunBundle\Tests\Dto\Template;

use Fun\FunBundle\Dto\Template\myTemplate;

class myTemplateTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testbuild()
    {
        $validation = $this->getMock('ValidationClass');
        $database = $this->getMock('DatabaseRepository');

        $confirm = new myTemplate($validation, $database);
    }
}
```

When i run `phpunit -c app/`

I get these errors:

> Argument 1 passed to
>   Fun\FunBundle\Dto\Template\myTemplate::__construct()  must be an
>   instance of Fun\FunBundle\Validation\ValidationClass, string given, 
>   called in
>   Dev/project/src/Fun/FunBundle/Tests/Template/myTemplateTest.php

myTemplate

```
class myTemplate
{


    /**
     * @var ValidationClass
     */
    private $validate;

    /**
     * @var DatabaseRepository
     */
    private $db;

    /**
     * @param ValidationClass $validation
     * @param DatabaseRepository $databaseRepository
     */
    public function __construct(
        ValidationClass $validation,
        DatabaseRepository $databaseRepository
    ) {
        $this->validate = $validation;
        $this->db = $databaseRepository;
    }
}
```

I came to a point where I have no idea how I can test myTemplate class :/ I do understand that the errors are relating to the injected services but how do i replicate or do this in my TestmyTemplate file?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to add the FQN (fully qualified name) of these classes to be able to mock properly. So you'll need to prefix ValidationClass with the full namespace, like `Some\Folder\Validation\ValidationClass`

Comment: Hey thx for tour replay, but i have already tired this and still exacly the sam error

Comment: u mean like this `$validation = $this->getMock('Fun\FunBundle\Validation\ValidationClass');`

Answer (score 0):

According to the PHPunit site on [defining Mocks](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.mock-objects), you first call `getMockBuilder` with the fully-qualified namepace/classname, and then `getMock()` returns the usable object.

```
$mock = $this->getMockBuilder('stdClass')
             //->setMethods(array('set')) # to be able to call a method
             ->getMock();
```